# Reversing a 'With Recursive' statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have the ff. query to show anyone under a Director's Hierarchy:

```
 WITH RECURSIVE emptree AS (
         SELECT e.win_id,
            e.full_name,
            e.current_sup_name,
            e.sbu,
            e.cost_center,
            e.lob,
            0 AS depth
           FROM app_reports.vw_hiearchy e
          WHERE e.win_id = xxxxxxx AND e.attrition_date IS NULL
        UNION ALL
         SELECT e.win_id,
            e.full_name,
            e.current_sup_name,
            e.sbu,
            e.cost_center,
            e.lob,
            t.depth + 1 AS depth
           FROM app_reports.vw_hiearchy e
             JOIN emptree t ON t.win_id = e.current_sup_win
          WHERE e.attrition_date IS NULL
        )
 SELECT emptree.win_id,
    emptree.full_name,
    emptree.current_sup_name,
    emptree.sbu,
    emptree.cost_center,
    emptree.lob,
    emptree.depth
   FROM emptree;
```

It works fine until I am requested to add another column (or more) to show who's the supervisor of a particular supervisor (technically adding columns dynamically - if possible, that shows all the supervisors from the bottom up). I'm not sure if it involves reversing this for me to actually get the hierarchy from the bottom-up and show it as current_sup_name_2, current_sup_name3, and so on. But I'm not sure how.

Thanks in Advance for any recommendations. :)

Comment: Do you actually require a separate column for each level of supervisor, or would it be acceptable to put the full hierarchy of supervisors inside a single (comma-separated?) field for each employee?

Comment: It is acceptable. :) , I can arrange them in PHP anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to show the full hierarchy of supervisors inside a single field with a small modification to the existing query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE emptree AS (
         SELECT e.win_id,
            e.full_name,
            e.current_sup_name,
            e.sbu,
            e.cost_center,
            e.lob,
            0 AS depth
           FROM app_reports.vw_hiearchy e
          WHERE e.win_id = xxxxxxx AND e.attrition_date IS NULL
        UNION ALL
         SELECT e.win_id,
            e.full_name,
            concat_ws(',', e.current_sup_name, t.current_sup_name) current_sup_name,
            e.sbu,
            e.cost_center,
            e.lob,
            t.depth + 1 AS depth
           FROM app_reports.vw_hiearchy e
             JOIN emptree t ON t.win_id = e.current_sup_win
          WHERE e.attrition_date IS NULL
        )
 SELECT emptree.win_id,
    emptree.full_name,
    emptree.current_sup_name,
    emptree.sbu,
    emptree.cost_center,
    emptree.lob,
    emptree.depth
   FROM emptree;
```

Comment: You could use `concat_ws(',', e.current_sup_name, t.current_sup_name)` instead of `||` which properly handles `null` values or empty strings.